# Restore RMAN Level 0 without any archivelogs?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, rman

I have a `level 0` backup, and `control files`, but I don't have the `archivelogs`. And I'm not using rman catalog.

I found ways to restore a `L0 backup`, if you have at least the first `archivelog` after the `L0`, or until the first missing `archivelog`, but yet I don't find how to restore the database as it was when the `L0` was created.

Is it possible to restore just the `L0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. A consistent full backup created in MOUNT mode does not require any archivelogs to be successfully restored.

An online backup is inconsistent and requires archivelogs for restoring a consistent state.

Comment: Ho. All our backups are made online. Then I guess at least the first archivelog is required, with `set until sequence xxxx` for example ? I don't have the first archivelog, due to an incident. This does not look good.

Comment: @Jean Coiron Without the archivelogs, you can not restore/recover a consistent state. You can restore the database without archivelogs, then open the database with the parameter `_allow_resetlogs_corruption` set to `true` as `alter database open resetlogs`, but that is not normal operation, this should be used only for salvaging whatever data you can before you rebuild the database.